# Graph: Algorithm for Grouping/Clustering by common edges

Tags: graph, grouping, cluster-analysis, nodes, edges

First of all I'm sorry if my english is a bit off (it's not my mother language). I'll try my best to make myself understood.

I'm making a visualization project for my master thesis and I've come up with an algorithm problem. The visualization consists of a graph that represents connections between what I call artefacts (the nodes of the graph) by what I call keywords (the edges). These artefacts can be a variety  of things. For example, they can represent photos and the edges would represent tags between the photos. For illustration purposes imagine Photo A connected to Photo B by Tag 1. This means that the Photo A and the Photo B both have the Tag 1.

Now, I have an operation called expansion that works this way:

A user double clicks on a node (in my example a photo) and the program queries the database for every new connection to that node. In the example above if a user double clicked on Photo B the expansion would generate, for example, Photo C and Photo D with Tags 2 and 3, respectively. The problem is that this can generate a lot of data leaving me with the solution of grouping nodes. The ideal would be to group with the maximum common keywords (edges) possible. For example, imagine now that Photo C and D both had the tag 5 there would be a group with C and D with the edge 5. But if Photo D and E both had tag 5 and 6, the group be D and E with edges 5 and 6, and then Photo C with edge 5 (edges can be repeated). To illustrate:

```
                             5,6
A----B -> expand B -> A----B-----DE
   1                    1  |
                           |5
                           |
                           C
```

My problem is getting this algorithm done. On the database I have the following tables:

**Keyword**
(keyword_id, other_attributes)

**Artefact**
(artefact_id, other_attributes)

**Keyword_Artefact**
(keyword_id, artefact_id)

**Keyword_Artefact_Artefact**
(keyword_id, artefact_id1, artefact_id2)

What would be the best approach to this problem? One that can be done with a fairly amount of data.

I'm developing this program in java, using the prefuse library.